# How to summarize date counts

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have 3 Worksheets. Following is an explanation of what I am trying to do.
EM11
EM12
EM01

The steps below are meant for Sheet EM11 but I want to repeat them FOR Sheet EM12 and Sheet EM01

- Select Sheet EM11
- Copy J2:J65636 and copy G2: G65636
- Create a new worksheet called EM11-Count
- Paste Column J into cell A2 of new worksheet called EM11-Count
- Paste Column G into cell B2 of new worksheet.
- Worksheet called EM11-Count now has dates in Range B2:B65636.
- Copy and paste the first date you get into cell C1
- Copy and paste the second date you get into cell D1
- Copy and paste the third date you get into cell E1
- Copy and paste the fourth date you get into cell F1
- Copy and paste the fifth date you get into cell G1
- Copy and paste the sixth date you get into cell H1
  (there will only be six or seven different dates)

Now the worksheet will look something like this

```
Col A  Col B       Col C      Col D      Col E       
                   04/1/2009  04/2/2009  04/3/2009
DPR1   04/1/2009            
DRS6   04/2/2009            
ERJ9   04/3/2009
```

Look at A2:B2.  Now look at C1:H1 to find the date that matches the date you have in B2.  Let’s say C1 has the matching date.  Go to C2 and put the number 1.

```
Col A  Col B       Col C      Col D      Col E       
                   04/1/2009  04/2/2009  04/3/2009
DPR1   04/1/2009   1        
DRS6   04/2/2009            
ERJ9   04/3/2009
```

Next Look at A3:B3.  Now look at C1:H1 to find the date that matches the date you have in B3. Let’s say D1 has the matching date.  Go to D3 and put the number 1.

```
Col A  Col B       Col C      Col D      Col E       
                   04/1/2009  04/2/2009  04/3/2009
DPR1   04/1/2009   1        
DRS6   04/2/2009              1         
ERJ9   04/3/2009
```

Next Look at A4:B4.  Now look at C1:H1 to find the date that matches the date you have in B4.  Let’s say E1 has the matching date.  Go to E3 and put the number 1.

```
Col A  Col B       Col C      Col D      Col E       
                   04/1/2009  04/2/2009  04/3/2009
DPR1   04/1/2009   1        
DRS6   04/2/2009              1         
ERJ9   04/3/2009                         1
```

Now repeat this pattern until every row in A:B has been covered.  Going down every row in the columns A:B random duplicates will occur.  For instance the contents in A1:B1 will be the same through A2:B7 or the contents in A14:B14 will be the same through A15:B20.  When these duplicates occur I want to delete the duplicate rows but increase the tally/count of the original row by the number “1”.  For example, after the macro is finished scanning A:B the worksheet might look like this

```
Col A  Col B       Col C      Col D      Col E       
                   04/1/2009  04/2/2009  04/3/2009
DPR1   04/1/2009   12       
DRS6   04/2/2009              23            
ERJ9   04/3/2009                         57
```

Here is the code I currently have.  As I am sure you can see it needs a lot of work.  Can you help me?

```
Sub NWorksheetArrange()
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C10:R65000C10"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "EM11-COUNT"
    Sheets("EM11").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="R2C7:R65000C7"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("EM11-COUNT").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If you can click edit so that you can see how the question looks in its original form.  The examples I gave might be hard to understand because the formatting changed after I posted the question.  Let me know if you have any questions.  Thank  you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds an awful lot like a "Pivot Table" ... and Excel does those automatically.

Like this: http://screencast.com/t/gpLsU50q38

To make a macro that builds the Pivot Table, do "Macro Record" ... then build the Pivot Table ... then wrap your code around the recorded Pivot Table statement.